# Socket connection from Unity to retrieve SUMO's vehicles

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, traffic

I would like to generate a 3D scenario for a traffic simulation.
The main idea would be having SUMO running a simulation and then getting the direction, speed and coordinates (X,Y) from each vehicle, so that I would create 3D models for this cars.

For this purpose, I was thinking about using some kind of TCP/IP communication between Unity and SUMO. Since this is possible while communicating SUMO with a network simulator such as OMNeT++, I was wondering if this would also be possible. I don't need to control the simulation in SUMO from Unity, just retrieve data regarding the vehicles in the network.

Unfortunately, I have no remarkable experience with Unity, so I cannot provide any code trying to achieve this...

EDIT:
As requested, I included some code. However, I only have code in Java.

```
String configFile = "test/resources/sumo_maps/Test2/Test2.sumo.cfg";
SumoTraciConnection trial = new SumoTraciConnection(configFile,-1);
trial.runServer();
Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = trial.getVehicleRepository().getAll().values();
                for(Vehicle car : vehicles){
                    bw.write(time + " // The vehicle with ID: " + car.getID()+ " is driving "
                            + "with a speed of "+ car.getSpeed() + " and is in coordinates x: " +car.getPosition().getX()+ 
                            " and y: " + car.getPosition().getY());
                    bw.newLine();
                }
```

Now, let's proceed to get a bit into the class SumoTraciConnection and its methods. This class is part of the mentioned (in the comments) library Traci4j.
It can be found in GitHub in case you need more info: https://github.com/egueli/TraCI4J/blob/master/src/java/it/polito/appeal/traci/SumoTraciConnection.java

The constructor:

```
public SumoTraciConnection(String configFile, int randomSeed) {
    this.randomSeed = randomSeed;
    this.configFile = configFile;
}
```

Now the runServer() method (I put the one with a boolean argument because if no parameter is given then it is automatically called with a false) Basically, this boolean is used to determine wheter the GUI version of SUMO or the console version will be ran:

```
public void runServer(boolean withGui) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        retrieveFromURLs(); //Checks if the configFile given has an "http://" at the beggining, in order to download the file

        int port = findAvailablePort(); //creates a Socket and finds a port with ServerSocket.getLocalPort()

        runSUMO(port, withGui); //It is used to run SUMO with different options, such as the configFile for the simulation, the remote port... sumoProcess is set here as: sumoProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(argsArray);, where argsArray contains the different options mentioned
        tryConnect(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), port, sumoProcess); // tryConnect basicaly calls this method tryConnectOnce, which connects as a client to the sumo process mentioned before, and does some checks that everything is correct.
        postConnect(); //I will explain this function after
    }
```

postConnect() initialices the DataInput and DataOutput streams and creates the repositories. I show now the relevant parts of the code:

```
dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));

    vehicles = new HashMap<String, Vehicle>();

    edgeRepo = new Repository.Edges(dis, dos, newIDListQuery(Constants.CMD_GET_EDGE_VARIABLE));
    addStepAdvanceListener(edgeRepo);

    laneRepo = new Repository.Lanes(dis, dos, edgeRepo, newIDListQuery(Constants.CMD_GET_LANE_VARIABLE));

    vehicleListQuery = newIDListQuery(Constants.CMD_GET_VEHICLE_VARIABLE);
    addStepAdvanceListener(new StepAdvanceListener() {
        public void nextStep(double step) {
            vehicleListQuery.setObsolete();
        }
    });
    vehicleListBefore = new HashSet<String>(vehicleListQuery.get());

    vehicleRepo = new Repository.Vehicles(dis, dos, edgeRepo, laneRepo, vehicles, vehicleListQuery);
    addStepAdvanceListener(vehicleRepo);
```

Where one StepAdvanceListener is just the following(I cannot explain exactly what is this for but I understand that is something that allow us to realize the new simulationstep has been done, so we have to update the repositories):

```
//Interface for an object that can be notified when the simulation advances by one step.

public interface StepAdvanceListener {

    /**
     * Callback for step advancement.
     * @param step the new simulation time, in seconds
     */
    void nextStep(double step);
}
```

Up to here, it would be the part related to the connection with SUMO. In the next edit (I need some rest right now..) I'll put the parts related with the Repositories and the Data retrieval

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unity can do tcp/ip but it is complicated. What port is SUMO listening to? Does SUMO create a server and wait for connection or does it try to connect to server on the network? What is the data format SUMO sends? You have no experience in unity so you dont have any code.......Do you have a working C++ or C# code that works with SUMO? I can help guide you to port it to unity if you have one....

Comment: Hello!
Tthere is a library called traci4j which, among other many functonalities, allows me to run a SUMO instance, load a simulation file and get the position and speed of the vehicles. It can be found here: https://github.com/egueli/TraCI4J 

It seems that this library is also available in C++, but I am not able to find it...

I have some working code in Java using this library that succesfully gets the position and speed of every vehicle.

Comment: So this means that SUMO does not support direct TCP connection. I don't know how TraCI4J  work.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that. If you launch SUMO with the option --remote-port "portnumber" then it keeps listening for incomming connections. Right now I am a bit busy, in a couple of hours I will update the post with some code. Thank you!

Comment: That was the first question I asked you...if it is server or client and you came up with traci4j answer.  Well, update when you have a code.

Comment: I am working on the post editing... I am trying to explain the main classes of the library (at the same time I try to understand some of them, because there are some which are being really hard to understand) but the post is getting really large.

I was wondering whether is it worth to explain all this code, because probably you won't feel like reading so much code. But if you dont mind.. OK! Do you think it would be better to have a Java program retrieving the data from SUMO and then sending it to Unity? (Let's say, SUMO is a server for the Java program and this one is a server for Unity).

Comment: If SUMO accepts clients, why even bother having Java communicate with it? You can just do this directly from C#/Unity....

Comment: I would even go one step further. If you do not need the data while the simulation is running, why don't you generate output files from sumo (for instance `--fcd-output`) and postprocess them to feed them into unity (you could use a named pipe reading them directly, if you fear they get too large)

Comment: The thing is that I need this while the simulation is running because changes in the vehicle network during the simulation might be done